# Translation of nested for loops into Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am struggling to translate this piece of a matrix multiplication in F# into Haskell (pls forget the parallel component):

```
Parallel.For(0, rowsA, (fun i->
        for j = 0 to colsB - 1 do
           for k = 0 to colsA - 1 do
              result.[i,j] <- result.[i,j] + a.[i,k] * b.[k,j]))  
    |> ignore
```

All I managed to put together is

```
sum (map (\(i, j, k) -> (my.read (a,i,k)) * (my.read (b, k, j))) [ (i, j, k) | i <- [0..rowsA], j <- [0..colsB], k <- [0..colsA] ]) 

--my.read reads the values of the respective cells from 'my' database
```

The intention is to read the cells of matrix a and matrix b from my database and do a matrix multiplication that eventually can be carried out in portions by different agents. This is controlled by setting the boundaries for i , j and k but is not relevant here.

I have tried to translate the above F# sample into haskell. The issue I am struggling with is that the result is not the sum over everything but there should be a list of results at the position i, j(F# result.[i,j] - the cell is the result matrix). I do not see how I could emit the right result (i,j). Maybe I  must further take this apart?

Comment: Currently this is a very low quality question. Instead of pushing the reader to guess about your intentions, please spend some time to formulate the actual question. Also try to isolate your problem from all the noise instead of commenting about it. Feels kinda strange that I have to explain such things to a user with 1.5K rep.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Did some edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly is the original code doing?  Also, what is the type signature of `my.read`?  I assume it would have a signature similar to `Num b => (a, Int, Int) -> IO b`, in which case this code will not even compile.  If `my . read` is in the IO monad, then you could write it as:

```hs
myfunc = do
    let indices = [(i, j, k) | i <- [0..rowsA],
                               j <- [0..colsB],
                               k <- [0..colsA]]

    -- Since `my . read` returns a value in the IO monad,
    -- we can't just multiply the values returned.
    r1 <- mapM (\(i, j, k) -> (my . read) (a, i, k)) indices
    r2 <- mapM (\(i, j, k) -> (my . read) (b, k, j)) indices

    -- We can multiply r1 and r2 together though,
    -- since they are values extracted from the IO monad
    return $ sum $ zipWith (*) r1 r2
```

The best advice I can give you right now is to use ghci to figure out your types.

Comment: Thanks, it is in deed in the IO monad. I was intending to make it polymorphic later on so that I eventually could do my.read (a,i,k) :: INT or my.read (a,i,k) :: Double.

Comment: Unfortunately, if a function does IO, you have to do everything in the IO monad.  This is difficult to do at first, but after you get used to it, it's a very nice system.  What's nice is that all your data processing can be done with pure functions (ones that do not do IO).  For example, here I would define a function that performs both reads and returns it as a tuple, then pass that tuple to my function that multiplies and sums them up.  I'll edit my answer to show what it'd look like.

Comment: On second thought, the only real improvement I could make to the above code would be to use the `<$>` and `<*>` operators from Control.Applicative to only loop over the indices once.  This is a rather small function, so moving the data processing function would simply be moving the `sum $ zipWith (*) r1 r2` to its own function.

Comment: Right, I meant :: IO Int or :: IO Double.

Comment: Is there nothing I could do w scoped type variables or parsing to cast eg an IO Int into an Int?

Comment: You can use unsafePerformIO, but as the name of the function suggests, this is not safe. By not safe, it means that you will have a function with side effects that does not tell everyone else that it has side effects. The entire reason for having the IO monad is so that it can contain any and all side effects. Inside a `do` block, you can extract do something like `a <- ioAction` where `ioAction` has type `IO Int`, then `a` would have type `Int`. I know it's weird and frustrating to have to code this way, but it becomes incredibly useful later. It is a feature, rather than a flaw, of Haskell.

Comment: I also know how bad it sounds to say that part of the language that is counter-intuitive is actually really useful, but it really does lend itself to encapsulation of side effects, modularity, and re-use.

Answer (score 3):

Try to divide

```
a :: [(a,a,a)]
a = [ (i, j, k) | i <- [0..rowsA], j <- [0..colsB], k <- [0..colsA] ]
```

into

```
b :: [[(a,a,a)]]
b = [ [ (i, j, k) | k <- [0..colsA]] | i <- [0..rowsA], j <- [0..colsB] ]
```

And you have a list of "lines" - matrix

And the list of sum is

```
m = [ [ (i, j, k) | k <- [0..colsA]] | i <- [0..rowsA], j <- [0..colsB] ]
listSum = map sum $ map (map (\(i,j,k) -> my_read (a,i,k) * my_read(b,k,j))) m
```